# Recovering Win10 from restore point deletes data but database and table remains in MariaDB

Tags: mariadb, mariasql, mariadb-connect-engine

I put MariaDB in ProgramData on Windows 10, create a system restore point, create a database in MariaDB, fill the database and roll back to the restore point, the database remains, but all the tables are empty, they open with an error table doesn't exist in engine
What can be wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by _"What can be wrong?"_  Are you asking what happen to the tables after the restore or are you asking why didn't the restore remove the whole thing (because, from my understanding you've created the restore point before you create a database)? Or do you just want to know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Why is data deleted after recovery?

Comment: When was the restore point taken?  Sounds like _after_ creating the tables, but _before_ loading them.

Comment: before creation